# Rails display Related or Similar posts from category on the post show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, related-content

I have `Post` and `category` models

```
Post
belongs_to :category

Category
has_many :posts
```

On a category show page, I’m able to display a list of all posts which belongs to this category by

```
<% Post.where(category_id: @category.id).each do |post| %>
....
<% end %>
```

categories_controller
....

```
def show
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all 
end
```

How can I display a list of related posts which belongs to the same category (or sharing the same category id), on one of the post’s show page. Thanks!

Comment: Category.friendly.includes(:posts) would fetch you all posts related to Friendly category

Comment: @praga2050  any update on the syntax to use on the show page? Your approach works but just looping the same post not showing the related. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you may do something like this in `posts_controller`:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  @relative_posts = Post.where(category_id: @post.category_id)
end
```

BTW, a good practice is using scopes instead of `where`:

```
Post
belongs_to :category
scope :of_category, ->(category) { where(category_id: category) }
```

So that in the controller you may do

```
@relative_posts = Post.of_category(@post.category)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please share the syntax to use on the post show page to fetch the related posts? I tried <% @related_posts.each do |post| %>....<% end %> and also <% Category.friendly.includes(:posts).each do |post| %>...<% end %> but both display list of the same post on its own page, not fetching related posts

Comment: Charlie, have you looked into the database? Are there any posts with needed `category_id` besides the current one?

Comment: Yes, I have checked in rails console and all the post have category_id. Also list  of posts with the same category_id show fine on the specific category page

Answer (score 1):

No need to use where condition as you already have associations between Post and Category. So you can modify following code

```
Post.where(category_id: @category.id)
```

as

```
@category.posts
```

So your show action present in `posts_controller.rb` should look like this

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @relative_posts = @post.category.posts
end
```

Now your view should be similar to

```
<% @related_posts.each do |post| %>
   // disply details of individual post 
<% end %>
```

Or you can avoid `@related_posts` variable by modifying each loop as  `<% @post.category.posts.each do |post| %>`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh, that makes sense in the posts_controller. what is the full syntax to use on the post show page to fetch the related posts?

Comment: using the above still displays **the same post** in multiples of related posts but not showing actual related posts. BTW I have used "related_posts" throughout instead of mixing with "relative_posts"

Comment: I'm trying to put this logic together in the posts_controller `@posts = Post.where.not(id: @post.id).belongs_to_category(@post.category.post, any: true)` I know .belongs_to_category is not a correct syntax but any idea how i can put it?

Comment: This query `@posts = @category.posts.where.not(id: @post.id)` might be help you.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. It still displays the same post in multiples of the related posts. May be there is something wrong with my db. I will play around it to find out.

Comment: Please check with different category posts, you might be checking post with same categories.

Comment: I checked but still same issue. Checked the app in detail, I just can't understand why it displays the same post repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

My bad, all along I was calling '@post' in the show view instead of 'post'

Controller should be:

```
@related_posts = Post.where(category_id: @post.category_id)
```

and

Post show view:

```
<% @related_posts.each do |post| %>
<%= post.name %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks all for your contributions